# Percentile calculation in powerbi using summarize() and groupby()

Tags: powerbi, dax

I m trying to findout 95th percentile for blackout by grouping the data by its OrgName, I got the output by using below query in PowerBI

```
X= SUMMARIZE(Query1,Query1[OrgName],"Percentile",PERCENTILE.INC(Query1[Blackout],0.95))
```

output of it only 60 % right, there is some deviation from the expected result.
so I m trying to use `groupby()` instead of `summarize ()`,  Below is my dax custom table function-

```
Org_GroupBy = GROUPBY(Query1,Query1[OrgName],"OrgName",PERCENTILEX.INC(CURRENTGROUP(),Query1[Blackout],0.95))
```

Below is the error I m getting

> Function 'GROUPBY' scalar expressions have to be Aggregation functions over CurrentGroup(). The expression of each Aggregation has to be either a constant or directly reference the columns in CurrentGroup().

Comment: I do not know the cardinality of OrgName, if it is very high, avoid Group By function. I suggest you to compare DAX output with expected results, most likely you will find that you you are not calculating the percentile on the same subset. For example, Excel percentile ignore NULL but they are considered in DAX percentile, you need to apply a filter.